# How to create an opportunity for a user to select a certain category, with printed out results

Tags: python

I have to display all of the expense records for a particular category; the user should be given the opportunity to choose the category as follows: “b” or “B” for beverages; “f” or “F” for food; “e” or “E” for entertainment; “t” or “T” for travel, “c” or “C” for clothing.
Here is what I have so far:

```
print("Expense record categories:")
print(" B or b for Beverages")
print(" F or f for Food")
print(" E or e for Entertainment")
print(" T or t for Travel")
print(" C or c for Clothing")
option = input(" Please select the category you would like to see:")
for item in expense_list:
    day = item[0]
    money = item[1]
    category = item[2]
    if option == 'b' or 'B':
         print(category)
```

I cannot figure out how to get all the beverage options from the csv file provided to me. ex. Monday 4.95 beverages, Tuesday 12.45 beverages. I have to do this for each category.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Notice how I made your post legible with 8 additional keystrokes. Formatting is something to keep in mind for the future.

Comment: Did you try to read in your csv file? How far did you get with it?

Comment: Yes the csv file is read into the program. This is just a section of the program I can't figure out. The csv file is a list of days, Sun-Sat and next to it is an amount of money and a category(shown above). When one of the options is selected I need to display all the days with that specific category(including the amount).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not filtering category based on input. It will be more helpful for contributors if you share the csv file loading and it's format. But I have made changes based on given code snippet. You can add more elif condition for other categories too. Also your condition to check input was wrong too.

```
print("Expense record categories:")
print(" B or b for Beverages")
print(" F or f for Food")
print(" E or e for Entertainment")
print(" T or t for Travel")
print(" C or c for Clothing")
option = input(" Please select the category you would like to see:")
for item in expense_list:
    day = item[0]
    money = item[1]
    category = item[2]
    if option in ['b', 'B'] and category == "beverages":
         print(day, " ", money, " ", category)
    elif option in ['f', 'F'] and category == "food":
         print(day, " ", money, " ", category)
```

Comment: The user is to enter one of the letters based on the category. I was trying to attach the file but, I didn't see where to do that. I can copy and paste what the file looks like.

Comment: @Tickner I have updated your code, your code had a wrong if condition. I fixed that issue, you can try updated code.

Comment: That update worked. Thank you for helping me. I am new to programming so the help is appreciated.

Comment: @Tickner Glad it helped! Please, consider accepting my answer